# Definitions of Continuity and Discreteness of Sets

Tags: real-analysis

In what sense (strict definitions/synonyms) is $\mathbb {R} $ continuous? Is this continuity antonymic to discreteness? What are the definitions of these properties?

Comment: [A good start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers).

Comment: So, is it just a set that is endowed with an order, is Dedekind complete (which apparently is equivalent to the supremum property), and is dense?